# check the existing of a inserted data in 1st table, if inserted data exist in the 1st table then add data into second table otherwise not inserted

Tags: php, mysqli

In php using mysqli First we want to check the existing of a inserted data in first table and if inserted data exist in the first table then add the inserted data into second table otherwise not inserted?

How we can do this?

Comment: did you tried something where is the code

Comment: You start by writing a bit of code that executes a SELECT query against the first table, and retrieves the result; then you write an if statement in your code that tests the result to see if the data exists..... you get the picture?

Comment: @MarkBaker you have any code related to this?

Comment: I'll rephrase my original comment: __You__ start by writing a bit of code that executes a SELECT query against the first table, and retrieves the result; then __you__ write an if statement in your code that tests the result to see if the data exists..... and if you have problems then, ask for help? But don't expect anybody to simply write it all for you

Answer (score 0):

**For Simplifying:**

You can consist a unique key for each value and test the key in table1 if exists then insert data into table 2.